# Creating images to use with repa-devil

Tags: haskell, repa

I am using `repa-devil` to read and write images. Now I need to programmatically create images. However, the `Image` constructors (such as `RGB`) in `Data.Array.Repa.IO.DevIL` all require foreign memory buffer arrays. Do I have to go off and learn how to work with that foreign pointer stuff (which sounds scary)? Or can I convert an unboxed array to the type I need?

```
emptyImage :: RandomGen r => (Int, Int) -> Rand r Image
emptyImage (w,h) = do
  xs <- getRandomRs (0, 255)
  let ps = take (w*h*3) xs :: [Word8]
  let arr = fromListUnboxed (Z :. w :. h :. (3::Int)) ps :: Array U DIM3 Word8
  let arr2 = ???how can I convert arr??? :: Array F DIM3 Word8
  return $ RGB arr2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use the more general `fromList` function.
That way, you can just do

```
...
let arr = fromList (Z :. w :. h :. (3 :: Int)) ps :: Array F DIM3 Word8
return $ RGB arr
```

The `fromList` function can be found in `Data.Array.Repa.Eval`

```
fromList :: (Shape sh, Target r e) => sh -> [e] -> Array r sh eSource
```

In general, you can ensure you produce the desired representation when you manifest your
arrays using the `computeP` function. So, you could have done something like
the following (if you don't mind the extra copying)

```
let arr = fromListUnboxed (Z :. w :. h :. (3::Int)) ps :: Array U DIM3 Word8
arr2 <- computeP arr
return $ RGB arr2
```

The type annotation is unnecessary as the compiler knows what type it needs to
be able to use the `RGB` constructor.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose really you need to write something different from random image. If you can construct pure indexing function, there is MUCH more efficient way to load array into memory, by means of `D`elayed array:

```
let delayed = fromFunction (Z :. w :. h :. (3::Int))
                           (\(Z :. x :. y :. comp) -> myComp)
foreignArr <- computeP delayed
```

With `yarr` library and `yarr-image-io` package - port of `repa-devil` it looks like:

```
let delayed =
        fromFunction (h, w)
                     (\(y, x) -> return $ VecList [myRed, myGreen, myBlue])
foreignArr <- dComputeP delayed
```

However, if you indeed want a random image, `yarr` allows to load array with stateful computation relatively fast:

```
import Data.Yarr
import Data.Yarr.Shape as S
import qualified Data.Yarr.Utils.FixedVector as V
import Data.Yarr.IO.Image

emptyImage :: StdGen -> Dim2 -> IO (Image, StdGen)
emptyImage gen sh@(h, w) = do
    arr <- new sh
    let writeRandColor gen i _ = do
            let (rgb, gen') = runRand (V.replicateM random) gen
            linearWrite arr i rgb
            return gen'
    gen' <- S.foldl writeRandColor (return gen) (const ()) 0 (size sh)
    touchArray arr
    return (RGB arr, gen')
```